# Formula defining the first transfinite ordinal $\omega$

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Just as an exercise in formula manipulation, I tried to find the simplest formula $\phi(x)$ with one free variable $x$ in the language of ZFC that defines the first transfinite [ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\omega$ (i.e. $\phi(x) \leftrightarrow x=\omega$). Here is my attempt (operator precedence follows the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Notational_conventions)):
$$\begin{align}\phi(x):=\exists a (a \in x) \land \forall a \forall b \forall c ((a \in x \lor a = x) \to (c \in b \to (b \in a \to c \in a))) \land \\
\forall a (a \in x \to (\exists b (a \in b \land b \in x) \land (\exists b (b \in a) \to \exists b (b \in a \land \neg \exists c (b \in c \land c \in a)))))\end{align}$$
It means that $x$ is non-empty ordinal ([transitive set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) with transitive elements) that is not a successor ordinal, but each its non-empty element is a successor ordinal.

Is this formula correct? Can anybody suggest further simplification?

Comment: Is the second conjunct supposed to be $$\forall a\forall b\forall c\bigg((a\in x\lor a=x)\to \big((c\in b\land b\in a)\to c\in a\big)\bigg)\;?$$ **Please** don’t rely entirely on operator precedence; use parentheses to make the thing more readable.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a few words explaining what it is you are trying to describe with the formulas? That might make checking it a bit easier. Also, is this simpler than writing out that $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set?

Comment: It appears that you’re trying to express: $x$ is non-empty and hereditarily transitive, and $\forall a\in x (a$ has a (not necessarily immediate) successor in $x$, and if $a$ is non-empty, it has an immediate predecessor$)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $\omega$ is an inductive set. It is the *minimal* inductive set.

$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(x):=\Bigg(\varnothing\in x&\land\forall w\Big(w\in x\rightarrow w\cup\{w\}\in x\Big)\Bigg)\\
&\land\forall y\Bigg(\bigg(\varnothing\in y\land\forall w\Big(w\in y\rightarrow w\cup\{w\}\in y\Big)\bigg)\rightarrow\forall w\Big(w\in x\rightarrow w\in y\Big)\Bigg)
\end{align*}$$

If you'd wish to avoid $\varnothing$ or $w\cup\{w\}$ they both can be replaced. It would make the formula considerably longer though. These two are defined as:

1. $x = \varnothing\iff\forall y(y\in x\rightarrow y\in y)$
2. $x=w\cup\{w\} \iff \forall z\Big((z\in w\lor z=w)\Leftrightarrow z\in x\Big)$

Comment: Nice! But it seems slightly longer in the expanded form than my first attempt.

Comment: @nikov: Either you're talking about the "fully expanded" version, or your original attempt is very badly written. Mine looks a lot better, in my opinion. The differences, anyway, should not sum in more than a short amount of letters.